# ícones via cdn não são exibidos no site

Tags: css, font-awesome, icons

Possuo um *card* e um *link* onde eu queria carregar um ícone de *download*, utilizo a classe fornecida pelo *font awesome*, porém o ícone não aparece. Já li sobre especificidade aqui mesmo no SO-pt, vi também que o estilo *inline* tem uma maior prioridade do que os demais seletores. Com base nisso gostaria então se possível saber qual fonte determinado ícone utiliza para eu poder usar o estilo *inline* e atribuir essa mesma fonte ou uma outra maneira de contornar isso sem que eu precise alterar o meu `font-family` do `body`, pois li que o ícone precisa de determinada tipo de fonte (desconheço qual) e que muito provável a atribuída ao `body` poderia ter uma maior prioridade?

**Segue o código:**

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     
    <div class="card mb-5 mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
        
          <img src="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

      <div class="card-body text-center">

       <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Lorem Ipsum</strong><br/></h5>

      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        
      <a href="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i>Currículo</a>

      </div>
          
     </div>
        
    </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara sei problema é que vc está usando as classe dos ícone da `versão 5` do FontAwesome, mas está importando no seu head a `versão 4` do FontAwesome... Basta mudar o link da versão para a que vc deseja... 

**Link da versão 4:** https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/download 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Linde da versão 5:** https://fontawesome.com/icons/download?style=solid 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olha ai eu não mexi em nada do código, só comentei o link que indexa a versão 4 e coloquei o da versão 5 e seu ícone apareceu...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

                <div class="card mb-5 mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">

                    <img src="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

                    <div class="card-body text-center">

                        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Lorem Ipsum</strong><br /></h5>

                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                        <a href="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i>Currículo</a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: mas teria como eu alternar entre as versões dos ícones no site do font awesome?

Comment: @LucasInácio não entendi o que vc quer alterar.... Se vc importar a versão 4 do FW vc tem que usar os as classes do link que sitei ali acima, porém os "desenho" dos ícones são um pouco diferentes entre a versão 4 e a 5. Além disso, na versão 5 tem uns ícones que são pagos, vc só consegue usar se comprar... Se precisar de algo comenta ai que te ajudo

Comment: queria saber onde ir para encontrar os ícones da versão anterior, mas consegui encontrar no rodapé do site, valeu!

Comment: @LucasInácio a tá rss, não tinha entendido o que vc quera :D, mas que bom que achou ai, qq coisa to na área. []´s